# Azure Application Gateway WAF and Spring Security form login setup

Tags: spring-boot, azure, spring-security, azure-application-gateway

I have Spring Boot Primefaces 10 application which implements Spring Security form login.
There is custom login page login.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:head>
    <link href="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Login</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false" class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-5 ">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-fluid center ui-noborder">
            <h2>Please sign in</h2>
            <p:outputLabel value="Login failed!" styleClass="red"
                           rendered="${!empty param['error']}"/>
            <p:inputText id="username" placeholder="User name" autocomplete="new-password"/>
            <p:password id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Login" ajax="false"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Spring security configuration:

```
  .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(
    "/resources/**",
    "/static/**",
    "/webjars/**",
    "/javax.faces.resource/**",
    "/",
    "/nadp.xhtml",
    "/notfound.xhtml",
    "/login.xhtml")
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**")
    .access(accessStringProvider.createAccessString())
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
    .failureUrl(IP_ADDRESS+"/login.xhtml?error=true")
    .defaultSuccessUrl(IP_ADDRESS+"/admin/index.xhtml", true)
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl(IP_ADDRESS + "/nadp.xhtml")
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .clearAuthentication(true)
```

It is working ok without Azure Application Gateway WAF, when IP_ADDRESS in spring configuration is just IP or domain name of machine where application is deployed.
when I'm trying to put into browser:

MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS/login.xhtml then everything is ok, I can login normally.

or:

MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS/admin/index.xhtml then I'm redirected to login page and I can login normally also

However when I configure Azure Application Gateway WAF (its backend is machine where application is deployed) and IP_ADDRESS in spring configuration is ip or domain of this Gateway, then when I'm trying to put into browser:

GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS/login.xhtml then everything is ok, I can login normally.

but when I'm trying:

**GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS/admin/index.xhtml then I'm redirected directly to backend machine (with its ip) login: MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS/login.xhtml instead of GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS/login.xhtml**

How to fix this behavior ? I want to be redirected to GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS/login.xhtml in such case.

I was trying to change in spring configuration

```
.loginPage("/login.xhtml")
```

to

```
.loginPage(IP_ADDRESS +"/login.xhtml")
```

but then logging in stopping to work completely (valid credentials doesn't work and I'm redirected to login page again).

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I've found solution:

We need to provide custom AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

        private final String url;

        @Override
        public void commence(
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {

            if (e != null) {
                httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(url + "/login.xhtml");
            }
        }
    }
```

and use it in spring configuration:

```
http
.exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint(IP_ADDRESS))
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
...
```